# Python script calls external program which comepletes correctly, yet remains as a running process?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've got a python script that calls this function multiple different times using different programs:

```
def mediaprocess(action):
    try:
        p = subprocess.Popen(action,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
        output, err = p.communicate()
        temp.write(str(p.returncode))
    except CalledProcessError as e:
        cleanandexit(1,e.message)
    finally:
        p.kill()
    return str(output)
```

However after my script completes successfully, one call I make to mkvmerge remains if I do ps aux, I get many, many of these processes (see below) still on the list?

```
plex       28571  0.0  0.0  12304  2784 ?        SNs  18:04   0:00 /usr/local/bin/mkvmerge -q -o /PlexStuff/PostProcess/newmkvfile.mkv /PlexStuff/PostProcess/tempvideo.mkv --language 0:eng /PlexStuff/PostProcess/Unsolved Mysteries (1987) - 2020-09-26 17 00 00 - Unsolved Mysteries.srt
```

I added the p.kill() to my script and it didn't make any difference. On the command line I have to do kill -9 to get rid of these old processes... but this shouldn't be necessary, all of the other programs I'm running ( mediainfo, handbrake, ffmpeg) all work perfectly.

What gives?

Comment: Does mkvmerge start a child process?

Comment: I think it does, yes. Looks like it is.Although it might be spawning a new process altogether. I'm not sure how to tell the difference?

Answer (score 0):

After some more messing around, and reading, I found that p.terminate() worked when p.kill() did not, so I'll just use that, still not certain the reason that program is behaving that way, but this works for now.